# How is the period of a remainder cycle related to the divisor?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I was looking into the cyclicity of remainders and stumbled upon this example: For $2^n$ mod $10$ the remainder sequence is as follows: $(2, 4, 8, 16, 2, 4, 8, 6,...)$. Thus, the period is $4$.

Similarly, multiplying the divisor by $2$ for $2^n$ mod $20$ the remainder sequence is as follows: $(2, 4, 8, 16, 12, 4, 8, 16, 12...)$. The period is $4$ again.

I was wondering how periods are related to different divisor multiples, specifically comparing the divisor sequence to its double and triple. How do they relate?

Comment: Google the "Carmichael function". In Wikipedia also the cycle property is mentioned , exactly what you observed here.

Answer (score 1):

When considering the general sequence

$$a_n=a^n, n=1,2,\ldots$$

we know that under the condition that $\gcd(a,m)=1$ holds, we have

$a^{\phi(m)} \equiv 1 \pmod m,$

where $\phi(m)$ is [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function), counting the number of positive integers less than $m$ that have a $\gcd$ of $1$ with it.

From that follows that $\phi(m)$ is a period of $(a_n)$, and with a bit of group theory we know that the smallest period is an integer divisor of $\phi(m)$.

If $\gcd(a,m)=d>1$, then let $p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_k$ be the prime factors of $d$.

Lets extract the respective powers of $p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_k$ out of $m$ and $a$:  $$m=p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}\ldots p_k^{\alpha_k}m', \gcd (m',p_1p_2\ldots p_k)=1.$$

$$a=p_1^{\beta_1}p_2^{\beta_2}\ldots p_k^{\beta_k}a', \gcd (a',p_1p_2\ldots p_k)=1.$$

It follows that $(p_1p_2\ldots p_k)|d$ and thus $\forall n \ge 1: (p_1^np_2^n\ldots p_k^n)|d^n|a^n$.

That means that for $n \ge \max (\alpha_1, \alpha_2,\ldots,\alpha_k)=n_0$, $a_n=a^n$ will always be divisible by all the powers of the $p_i$ that consideration $\pmod m$ cares about.

In other words, $a_n$ will from some $n_0$ on be a multiple of $p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}\ldots p_k^{\alpha_k}$ and from then on those prime factors don't matter any more and can be disregarded. This follows from the [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) that says in its simplest form that if $m=m_1m_2$ and $\gcd(m_1,m_2)=1$, then

$$x \equiv y \pmod m$$ is equivalent to

$$x \equiv y \pmod {m_1}, \; x \equiv y \pmod {m_2}.$$

In our case we have $m_1=p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}\ldots p_k^{\alpha_k}, m_2=m'$, and we have $a^n \equiv 0 \pmod{m_1}$ from some $n_0$ on.

Putting this together, that means in the general case where exponent and modul are not relatively prime, we can reduce the problem to finding the period of $a^n \pmod {m'}$.

Looking at your example, we have $a=2, m=10$ initially, we see that $d=2$, so we need to look at $2^n \pmod 5$ only. $\phi(5)=4$, so we know that the smallest period will be a divisior of $4$, which is consistent with the $4$ you found.

When you go to $m=20$ as modul, we see that this doesn't change the reduction process above, we still end up with $m'=5$. That explains why the period for $m=20$ is still $4$.

Generally, when you are dealing with large modules, it pays off to consider each prime power in the prime factorisation of $m$ independently. The Chinese remainder theorem makes sure you can do that. Once you found the smallest period for each prime power, the least common multiple of them will be the smallest period of the whole modul.